# How to use REDUCE on a list of relationships with a possibility of non-existent property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a way to get a default value from [:OWNS].percentageOfOwnership if that property doesn't exist in the OWNS relationship.

I have a graph with Persons and Corporations as nodes; and OWNS as relationship. My current script retrieves the leaves of the sub-graph rooted from a particular Corporation node and it's total percentage of ownership by multiplying the percentageOfOwnership values of all the OWNS it passes through so OWNS typically has a percentageOfOwnership property. But sometimes, it doesn't exist and it ruins the script.

It works when all relationships have percentageOfOwnership.

```
WITH "Y Corp" AS corpName, 25 as minPercentTotal
MATCH cp=(c:Corporation{name:corpName})<-[:OWNS*]-(p:Person)
WITH *, relationships(cp) AS o
WITH *, REDUCE(perc = 1, ps in o | perc * ps.percentageOfOwnership) as percent
WITH DISTINCT p, SUM(percent)*100 as percentTotal, minPercentTotal
WHERE percentTotal >= minPercentTotal
RETURN p.name as Shareholder, percentTotal AS `% Owned`
ORDER BY percentTotal DESC
```

Shareholder % Owned
"Mr. 4" 32.00000000000001
"Mr. 2" 25.0
"Mr. 1" 25.0

This is the result for the graph without missing percentageOfOwnership properties.

Comment: What do you mean by it ruins the results?

Comment: If `percentageOfOwnership` is not present then the ownership is unknown and empty result is not an issue as the value is not known. What do you expect if one of the relationships does not have value?

Comment: And if you do want to use a default value for `percentageOfOwnership` (as in @ran's answer), what should the default value be? Using `0` as the default would give you a `percent` value of `0`, which is probably not what you want. But using any arbitrary non-zero value seems wrong too. I think you need to fix your DB so that all `OWNS` relationships have the correct non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coalesce](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce) function to return a default value in case of the property doesn't exists, for example:

WITH *, REDUCE(perc = 1, ps in o | perc * coalesce(ps.percentageOfOwnership, 1)) as percent

will use 1 as a default value if percentageOfOwnership doesn't exists.